# Updating php.ini with extension=php_mongodb.dll returning NULL is command prompt (Laravel | jenssegers / laravel-mongodb)

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, xampp, laravel-mongodb

Trying to install jenssegers/laravel-mongodb. Downloaded MongoDB PHP driver (1.9.1 DLL) from https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb. Placed it in C:/xampp/php/ext/ folder. Updated php.ini file by adding extension=php_mongodb.dll. Once I add this line in php.ini XAMPP will get crashed saying below error.

[image: Apache XAMPP error]

Tried changing the port number also, but still not working.
Another thing noticed is, once php.ini is updated, none of the PHP commands run in the command prompt. It just returns nothing. (Commands like php artisan or composer update)

[image: Commands giving NULL return]

composer, mongodb are updated to latest version. PHP version is 7.3.0

Comment: Are you sure the mongo extension imatches your Apache. I mean 32bit or 64 bit like you Apache? Also did you download the Thread Safe (TS) version. The NTS version wont run with APache configered in XAMPP

Comment: Yes, I have downloaded 64 bit DLL file as my system is also 64 bit. And yes I tried both NTS and TS. Both not working!!

Comment: Still waiting for solution